# Bash script which uploads (small) images as documents into MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, shell, gridfs

I have a directory with loads of small images (say `png` icons) which I want to store in my MongoDB *without* using GridFS, ideally using a bash script and the mongo shell alone. From what I read, that seems technical feasible, but I did not yet manage to get it working. The [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/meta/images-guide/) but the recipe seems incomplete. 
According to [Christoph Menge](http://menge.io/2015/03/24/storing-small-images-in-mongodb/), GridFS is indeed not absolutely necessary for e.g. icons only.

Assume, I have a image file called `foo.png` which I would like to persist into the database `icons`, the GridFS solution would be this:

```
mongofiles -u "uploader" -p "notsogreat" --authenticationDatabase "admin" -d icons put foo.png
```

**But how do I do that without GridFS within `bash`?**

```
base64 foo.png > mongo -u "uploader" -p "notsogreat" --authenticationDatabase "admin" [SOME_MAGIC]
```

StackOverflow pages I consulted (in no particular order):

- [Store images in a MongoDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796914/store-images-in-a-mongodb-database)
- [Store images in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327746/store-images-in-mongodb)
- [How can I add images in mongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749702/how-can-i-add-images-in-mongodb)
- [Read image file into a MongoDB document's binary field via mongo shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004242/read-image-file-into-a-mongodb-documents-binary-field-via-mongo-shell-script)
- [How do I insert a binary file into mongodb using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965515/how-do-i-insert-a-binary-file-into-mongodb-using-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Redirecting the output to a text file in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207907/redirecting-the-output-to-a-text-file-in-mongodb)
- [How to add binary data with objectId to mongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850650/how-to-add-binary-data-with-objectid-to-mongodb)
- [Read a file from a mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290113/read-a-file-from-a-mongo-shell)

Further reference(s):

- https://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/how-to-store-images-in-a-mongodb-database/

Comment: I just learned about `var content = cat('foo.png.b64'); db.icons.insert({'picture':content})` if I did `base64 foo.png > foo.png.b64` upfront.